# Tampermonkey jQuery require not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tampermonkey

I am trying to modify a piece of code I wrote for Grease Monkey to make it compatible with Tampermonkey. Tamper monkey keeps saying '$' is not defined despite my @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js. The require works on Greasemonkey.

The Tampermonkey instaled function(s) overview recognizes the JQuery require.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Function
// @version  1
// @run-at   document-end
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var userIP;

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", // Getting user Ip Address
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        userIP = data.ip; // Saving user Ip Address
    }
});
```

Comment: (1) What browser & version are you using? ... (2) What errors do you get in the browser console? ... (3) Is the ` '$' is not defined` message just in the Tampermonkey editor?

Comment: @BrockAdams 1, Firefox - the latest version, 61.0  2, TypeError: $ is undefined  3, yes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you say it is only in the editor this is probably Tampermonkey's syntax checking not loading required scripts, and using them as part of the code checking process. So it just sees that a variable has not been declared anywhere in the user script itself and shows the warning. The script should still work as expected.

If the messages annoy you, you can clear them by explicitly declaring the `$` variable at the top of your script like so:

```
var $ = window.jQuery;//OR
var $ = window.$;
```

Comment: Your solution solves my problem but it causes the webpage loading time to increase, from ~1 second to ~31 seconds

Comment: @SethWheeler The code provided doesn't cause that, it is the fact that you set the ajax setting `async: false,` this tells the browser to do a synchronous request which will freeze up the browser till that request is done (hence why it is depreciated, check the console for the warning)

Comment: You were correct thank you for your help, I forgot about the async

Answer (score 17):

Greasemonkey uses the [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net) text editor combined with the [JSHINT](https://jshint.com) linter.

In order for the JSHINT to recognize global variables declared outside of your code, you need to define them using an inline comment. For example, to tell JSHINT about jquery, use this:

```
/* globals $ */
```

See https://jshint.com/docs/#inline-configuration

Comment: This is a better answer. It also lets you disable the warning from addressing global variables already present on the target page.