# Can't use jQuery on TamperMonkey extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use jQuery on TamperMonkey, so I added the requiered on the head like this

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Sliver.tv Bot
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Sliver.tv betting bot
// @author       Pachi
// @include      https://www.sliver.tv/win/fortnite
// @include      https://www.sliver.tv/win/pubg
// @include      https://www.sliver.tv/win/csgo
// @match        https://www.sliver.tv/win/fortnite
// @match        https://www.sliver.tv/win/pubg
// @match        https://www.sliver.tv/win/cs
// @match        https://www.sliver.tv/win/*
// @match        https://www.sliver.tv/win*
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(".waw-prediction-card").each(function (index) {



        var SeleccionDeCarta = $(".waw-prediction-card").eq(index);
        var SeleccionDeOpciones = $(SeleccionDeCarta).find(".waw-prediction-choice--active");
        var CantidadDeOpciones = SeleccionDeOpciones.length;
        var Random = Math.floor(Math.random() * CantidadDeOpciones);


        var SeleccionFinal = $(SeleccionDeOpciones).eq(Random);
        SeleccionFinal[0].click();



    });
```

but my script is not working. I have this yellow triangle next to "$" saying $ is not defined, maybe the require is not working right?

Comment: i am not sure what u mean, i edited with full script

Comment: i re-created the script first adding the requiere, save and then the script and save, sasme error ;(

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried accessing `window.$`, rather than just `$` in your script to see if it works?  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090754/tampermonkey-jquery-require-not-working

Comment: i tried and the error dissapear but the script is not working yet, but if i execut on the console of chrome works

Comment: Remove `@grant none` and never use it unless you **really** need to run the code outside of sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you have to do. Add this code before `$(".waw-prediction-card")`:

```
var $ = window.jQuery;
```